# Why are lungfish cartilaginous?

Tags: ichthyology

Lungfish have a cartilaginous notochord, and a reduced cartilaginous skull. Is this feature to improve flexibility, or is there another reason?

Comment: Your question is interesting and relevant to here, but it's expected that you show you have researched and tried to find answers to your question before you post, rather than expect others to do it all. Could you include it in your post?